# How does this iterative reverse method work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reverse

I have been building small programs for the last 2 months while also taking a few courses online to help me learn coding. It's been going well and I feel like the question I am about to ask is something simpler than some of the stuff I've written.

Below are two methods to reverse a string. I understand method 2, I do not understand how method 1 works. They both give the same output. Can anyone explain how the first method works?

1.

```
def reverse(string)
  reversed_string = ""

  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string

    i += 1
  end

  return reversed_string
end
```

2.

```
def rev(string)
  string.reverse
end
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It is quite straightforward. If in general you don't know how to analyse algorithms, the best way is to pick an example (like `string = "fun"`) and then execute the program on paper. ("`reversed_string` starts as empty, `i` as `0`; `i` is less than `3` so we continue the loop; then `reversed_string` becomes `"f" + ""`, which is `f`; `i` is now `1`, `1` is still less than `3`: `reversed_string` is now `"u" + "f"`, which is `"uf"`....) If you have any specific problem in understanding this code, ask the specific question.

Comment: @Amadan:  You *really* should just answer the question.

Comment: Just so that you know, an experienced Rubiests would *never* write a method that looks like #1. That's C disguised as Ruby. One would instead use an enumerator. For example: `def reverse(string); string.each_char.reduce('')  { |s,c| c+s }; end`.Let's try it: `reverse("aibohphobia") #=> "aibohphobia"`. (The meaning of that word is "fear of palindromes".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd encourage you to open `irb` in your terminal and experiment with what effect each line of this method would have. You can read all the explanations in the world, but you'll only get a solid feel for how the language works by typing stuff in and seeing output on the screen.

A String is basically an array or a long list of characters, eg. `["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`. Method #1 sets up a `while` loop that repeatedly takes an action once per each character in the string. More specifically, it takes the character at each position (`string[i]`) and adds it to the *beginning* of a "result" string (`reversed_string`) which gradually grows until it's as long as the original string was. Except each letter is added to the *beginning* of the result string, so if the original string is "Hello!", the result string will start with an `"H"`, then will become `"eH"`, then `"leH"`, and so on.

Big-picture note: If you're learning to program for the first time, this is all well and good; Ruby is a fantastic language choice with a thriving and friendly community, and this style of `for` or `while` loop is a staple of most languages and are well worth learning and practicing. But you should be aware that **the logic used in method #1 is not idiomatic Ruby**; yes it will work fine, but I think most experienced Ruby developers would look at that code and say "Ick. Why didn't you just take the array and run `.each` on it?" Ruby is a very flexible language but certain code patterns have emerged as common or "favorite" practices, and in my experience, the structure where you use an integer to step through a `while` loop isn't one of them.

Keep that in mind, and once you get through your current learning materials, consider looking around to find a course that teaches you Ruby in "the Ruby way".

Answer (score 1):

The first method is simply prepending each character of the original string to a new string, which results in the reversal of the string itself.

`string[i] + reversed_string` means:

- Take the ith position of the string
- Prepend it to `reversed_string`

Since `reversed_string` starts empty, this works conveniently well.

For a string "apples", that would result in:

- `'a' + ''`
- `'p' + 'a'`
- `'p' + 'pa'`

...and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `string = 'Hello'`

When `i = 0`, `string[0]` is referring to `H` and `reversed_string` is ``.  Therefore, after `reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string`, `reversed_string` is `H`.

`i` is then incremented.

When `i = 1`, `string[1]` is referring to `e` and `reversed_string` is `H`. Therefore, after `reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string`, `reversed_string` is `eH`.  `e` is concatenated to the front of the `reversed_string` string.

`i` is then incremented.

When `i = 2`, `string[2]` is referring to `l` and `reversed_string` is `He`. Therefore, after `reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string`, `reversed_string` is `leH`.  `l` is concatenated to the front of the `reversed_string` string.

`i` is then incremented.

The loop continues until `i` equals `string.length`, meaning there are no more letters to move to the front.